# Scrape from javascript generated grid

Tags: python, selenium

I try to make a project in Python which needs full list of metal bands from https://www.metal-archives.com/browse/letter . The problem is that when you go to any letter you don't get the full list, but just a chunk of maximum 500 bands (I need only urls from them). To get next chunk you should click a button, and I don't know both how to trigger button in code and how to scrape data after it. What I googled is that I should use selenium, but I'm not sure and I can't understand what it really does.

Also, I tried to use https://github.com/jonchar/ma-scraper/blob/master/MA_band_scraper.py to scrape data, however, script seems to be too old and doesn't work properly anymore. Explanations on what it does wrong are in the issues https://github.com/jonchar/ma-scraper/issues/3 .

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use browser developer tools to analyze the HTTP request that is being performed (if any) to get the next page of results.

If you want to "interact" with the page, you would need to use a webdriver + Selenium. The webdriver is like a common web browser (Firefox, Chrome) that you control from your code, through Selenium. You program stuff like open this URL, search the "Next" button, click it... and then you can obtain the HTML code from the current page and scrape it.